# CMD file executed from VBA leads to different results

Tags: vba, excel, cmd

**PROBLEM IS SOLVED ALREADY**

this should be fairly simple, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I have a cmd file in V:\something\XYZ.cmd, which takes 1 parameter.
When I execute it manually, e.g. Windows-Explorer and double-click the cmd, I get my result.

Now I have a XLSM file on my Desktop and a macro should invoke this cmd instead.
Problem is, when executed that way, I get some "file-not-found errors" in the cmd itself.

So how could I simulate the manual execution of the cmd.
There must be some path related problem...

This is how I execute from VBA:

```
Call Shell("cmd.exe /c " & "V:\something\XYZ.cmd" & " " & someParameter, vbNormalFocus)
```

I tried to put a

```
ChDir "V:\something\"
```

right before the call, but that doesn't change anything...

Where's the problem?

Comment: What is the difference in your results?

Comment: The environment variables may be different depending on how you invoke the script.  Verify the script gets invoked by the same user-account.  Add debugging to show the value of PATH and other environment variables then compare the result with each invocation method.

Comment: Guys, thank you, I just found the error myself:

Comment: There was a %root% used inside the script, this was the error

Answer (score 0):

thank you, I just found the error myself:
There was a %root% used inside the script, this was the error. Changed it to absolute path, now it works